# Activity always show first fragment when configuration change?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity, it's layout have a FrameLayout, where multiple Fragments switch back and forth
In the first time application open, the Fragment 1 is open, I did that by 
calling :

```
if (savedInstanceState == null)
    addFragment1();
```

After using for a while a switch to Fragment 2, but when Configuration Change happen, Activity just turn back to the Fragment 1, Why ?

I realize if I setRetainInstance(true) for all fragment, this won't happen, should I setRetainInstance in this situation ?

Answer (score 1):

Because when configurationChanged, if you don't add "configChanges" in Manifest, the current Activity will be destroy and is replaced by a new re-created activity, 
But when you setRetainInstance(true), the fragments in your current activity will be detach and re-attach in the new re-created acitivty.(if set to false, all the fragment will be destroy and recreate with the activity).
So in your case, I think setRetainInstance is ok.
But you should consider use "configChanges" in Manifest if your activity doesn't need to recreate when configureChanged.
Also check to make sure all the backstacks still work.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, i knew that new activity instance will replace, let's not talk about add configChanges in Manifest because i dont want to use that for some reason.
The question was, because I added 2 fragments into it and **didn't remove any at all**, and the first fragment only added the first time in,  when configuration change happen, new instance of activity create, two new instance of fragment is still added to FragmentManager by the same old TAGs, but activity switch back to fragment 1 instead of 2, where i was before configuration change, can you explain this ?

Comment: Do you override onSaveInstanceState? If not, when new activity instance recreate (it's will be a completely clean like the first time you open activity), the savedInstanceState will be null, and then yours first fragment will be add.

Comment: Well, i checked and saw savedInstanceState will be null the first time we open the application, and it's not null after configuration change, whether i override onSaveInstanceState or not

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, the saveInstance will be auto write by the fragmentManager. I looked in source code of Android but still don't know why it switch back to fragment 1, maybe it's because somehome your fragment 2 became inactive. But I still haven't found the reason yet.